# would turning the rotors make my front end go out of alignment?

Tags: brake-rotor, alignment

Since I had my rotors turned my front end now pulls to the right where it didn't before. Are the two related?should they gave realigned my front end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not *normal* for the front end to go out of alignment when getting the front rotors turned, but it would not be unheard of. Any time you mess with the front end of the vehicle you run the risk of needing an alignment. This is not something you should expect to be done, though.

Something which may be happening is you may have a caliper which is dragging, causing the vehicle to pull to the one side. *This* would have something to with the work which was done.